# Default imports groovy

Tags: groovy

> groovy defualt imports

Is it possible to have our own package in default imports? Is there any way to tell the groovy runtime to use my own package as default import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3041) covers you question.

The bulk of it  is here.

```
 class DefaultImportSourceUnitOperation extends SourceUnitOperation {
     public void call(SourceUnit source) throws CompilationFailedException {
         source.getAST().addImportPackage("pkg1.pgk2.pkg3.");
     } 
}

 class DefaultImportClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
     protected CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource
 codeSource) {
         CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, codeSource)

         cu.addPhaseOperation(new DefaultImportSourceUnitOperation(), Phases.CONVERSION)

         return cu
     }
}
```

Be sure not to forget to add the `.` to the end of the package declaration.

Goodluck!

Comment: how can i use this, i will create a separate jar with this groovy file then uses DefaultImportClassLoader ?

Answer (score 2):

Since Groovy 1.8 there is an easier way with [`ImportCustomizer`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.11/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/ImportCustomizer.html):

```
def importCustomizer = new ImportCustomizer()
importCustomizer.addImports('com.looneytunes.Coyote', 'com.looneytunes.RoadRunner')
importCustomizer.addStarImports('com.acme')
importCustomizer.addStaticStars('com.looneytunes.Physics')
def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(importCustomizer)
def shell = new GroovyShell(configuration)
shell.evaluate """
    new Coyote().startPlanToCatch(new RoadRunner())  // no need for explicit imports
        .useContraption(new PortableHole())          // from com.acme
        .withPhysicsViolation({ forgetGravity(it) }) // method from com.looneytunes.Physics
        .start()
"""
```