# Groovy script without default imports

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

#### Problem

With Groovy's [default imports](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_default_imports) any script has access to `java.{lang,util,io,net}.*`, `groovy.{lang,util}.*`, `java.math.BigInteger`, and `java.math.BigDecimal` without importing anything.

What if I want none of that?
**Is it possible to create a `GroovyShell` that would not have any default import?**

---

#### Example demonstrating the issue

```
def importCustomizer = new ImportCustomizer()
// importCustomizer.clearImports()   <-- I wish that would exist
def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(importCustomizer)
def binding = new Binding("Date", "today")
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding, configuration)
println shell.evaluate("Date")
```

It prints `class java.util.Date`.
I'd like to get `today` instead, using `Date` from the binding.
(It's just an example, inspired by [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44401669/8022004)).

---

#### What I have tried so far

With [`CompilerConfiguration`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.html) and [`ImportCustomizer`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.11/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/ImportCustomizer.html), I can only *add more imports*, I don't know how to start from a clean slate.

I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938791/6730571) (for which I just fixed the dead link), which pointed me to [where those default imports are defined](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.html#DEFAULT_IMPORTS), but I don't see a way to *remove* imports, again it's only about adding more.

It looks like I have to hook ["Semantic Analysis" phase](http://joesgroovyblog.blogspot.fr/2011/09/ast-transformations-compiler-phases-and.html):

> This includes resolving classes, static imports and scope of variables.

Using `groovyConsole` confirms this: if I type `x=Date` in there, then use "Script" menu → "Inspect AST", the tool shows:

- after "Conversion" I still have `x=Date`
- after "Semantic Analysis" I see `x = java.util.Date`

And at that phase the [ResolveVisitor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.html#DEFAULT_IMPORTS) does its thing (using default imports) and I have not found a way to get around that.

Comment: Not really what you're after but worth a look https://github.com/kohsuke/groovy-sandbox

Comment: @MikeW Hmm yes I know about that one, I've actually [done something similar myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720460/6730571), but Kohsuke's is probably vastly better and deserves that I take a closer look: maybe there will be new hints in there, thanks :)

Comment: That gave me new insights, but I still can't get around that pesky [ResolveVisitor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.html#DEFAULT_IMPORTS) that uses default imports to resolve :(

Comment: Argh! My question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703343/how-programmatically-remove-default-import-in-groovy). I did search earlier and failed to find it... (and it says there is no other solution than altering the global array in `ResolveVisitor`, which is not acceptable as a general solution). But I've put much more details here, so I'm reluctant to remove it :-/